# Drawint Bitmap on Android's Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

How to draw a Bitmap on Android's Canvas with specified width, height, positionX, positionY? There is no such method in Canvas.drawBitmap(..); and resizing Bitmaps requires Android API 19 and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no such method in Canvas.drawBitmap(..);

Really?
Take a look at the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

There are a lot of methods, for example:

```
drawBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint)
```

or

```
drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)
```

Try something and let me know, if this doesn't help you

**UPDATE:**
You can do the following:
1) scale bitmap

```
createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

Available from API 1 ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap), int, int, boolean))
2) draw bitmap at position (x, y):

```
drawBitmap(Bitmap, left, top, paint)
```

Available from API 1
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap), float, float, android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: Creating an array of colors seems a bit coplicated and the second one didn't exactly worked for me.